# Visual Web developer - console application , how to

Tags: c#, console-application, visual-web-developer

I am learning in the visual web developer c#, entity framework, and webservices.
I want to be able to run the entity framework for example with out building it a gui, or run a browser.
So condole application with reference can do the job.
Can I add a console application to my  Visual Web developer solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 41, accepted):

FWIW.  In VWD 2010, you can create a library project, then go under project properties and change the project to Console application, and create a method "public static void Main(String[] args) {}", and it will build a console app for you.

Comment: Thank you!  This is a great tip.  It looks like there are plenty of people who don't know you can do this.  I think you can do the same with creating Win32 GUI apps as well.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped.  I don't even remember what VWD *is*, and pretty much all my SO reputation for 2013 comes off this question.

Comment: this was great tip i was about to  install VS but found this answer and  it was great help thumbs up :))

Comment: According to the book I'm working from (geared towards VS2013), there should be an App.config file, but there isn't one to be seen.  Is this anything I need to worry about?

Answer (score 0):

No. You will need Visual C# Express. VWD only works with web projects. Visual C# Express should have this project template.

Comment: But inside Visual C# Express I cant create webservice.... how can I solve this? thanks

Comment: To add a web reference, right click your project and choose add web reference.

Comment: I have only add webservice reference, but i want to add the entire project as a reference, thanks